# Pass Function To Main Method Args Cmd Prompt

Tags: c#, function, args

i am trying to pass a add or subtract function to main method args. in cmd if i run the program with 1 it should display the AddFunction and if i press it with 2 it should display the minusFunction. this is what i have done so far im a little stuck

```
using System;

namespace addSubtractProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Add and Subtract Program!");
            Console.WriteLine("============================");

            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                if (args[0] == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You are using the AddFunction");
                    (AddTwo);
                }
                else if (args[0] == "2")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You are using the subtractFunction");
                    (subtractTwo);

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                int x = 10, y = 5;
                int z = AddTwo(x, y); // function that returns a value
                int i = subtractTwo(x, y);

            }
        }

        //function Add Two Numbers
        static int AddTwo(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a + b);
        }

        //function Minus Two Numbers
        static int subtractTwo(int a, int b)
        {
            return (a - b);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little modification, you can do this:

```
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        int x = 10, y = 5;
        if (args[0] == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are using the AddFunction");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result = {0}", AddTwo(x,y) ));
        }
        else if (args[0] == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are using the subtractFunction");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result = {0}", subtractTwo(x,y) ));
        }
    }
```

Hopefully, this can give you some ideas. The code can be improved even further and I'll leave this for you to try by yourself.

Comment: Thanks Tao this worked.  I will explore other options to achieve this too.  
is there another way to call the function to main method without using 
(string.format(result={0)

Comment: Since both `AddTwo` and `subtractTwo` look similar (same argument types, same return type), you can consider calling either of them via *delegate* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx